# How to simplify this dictionary creation with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this:

```
for char in alphabet:
    positions[char] = i
    i += 1
```

and I am trying this:

```
[positions[char] = i for char in alphabet i+=1]
```

but I am not sure about increment of *i*.

[and I get the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9evE.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a `dict` comprehension:

```
positions = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(alphabet)}
```

This will start with `i=0` you can pass the start index as a parameter to `enumerate`:

`enumerate(alphabet, 1)` will start indexes at `1`. For a general incrementing loop variable, you can use `itertools.count` as mentioned in the comments, or just loop over a `range`:

```
positions = {alphabet[i]: i for i in range(len(alphabet))}
```

Comment: alternatively, create the iterator in the "correct" order using `zip` and `count` so you don't need a dictcomp and delegate everything to builtins: `dict(zip(alphabet, itertools.count()))`

Comment: `zip` and `count` requires an import to mimick a built-in. I don't know about that. Why would I not want a dictcomp?

Comment: Because it more clearly expresses intent, or because you're already using itertools, or because it's infinitesimally faster (on 3.8.1, applied to `string.ascii_letters` I get ~2.35usec versus ~2.75 for the comprehension)

Comment: @Masklinn, you can apply [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) -> `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(alphabet)))`

Comment: I am aware of all of the mentioned approaches (which are valid), but knowing the proper dict comp syntax and `enumerate` is just more instructive and useful for someone at the OP's level.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, it's two different styles - object-oriented and functional.

Comment: @OlvinRoght true, `reverse` as a `flip` is somewhat less clear though, and it means a function call per item, something CPython is not very good at (on the same ad-hoc benchmark as the others I get about 9.7usec). It's possible that pypy would happily chew through it though.

Comment: @OlvinRoght well after installing the latest pypy, the reverse() solution has an even poorer showing there (10.3 us +- 0.5 us), though the dictcomp edges out over the zip solution (1.86 us +- 0.10 us versus 2.62 us +- 0.11 us).